# PHP code not showing the SQL data

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL query in PHP:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime_accessed , '%y,%m,%d') 
FROM e_track_access_log 
WHERE datetime_accessed = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY AND member_id >'0' 
ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

What I am trying to do is draw information from the SQL database to only show information from the current day. The problem now is I am not getting any data from the SQL displayed.

My Column is a DateTime format I cannot change that as this is how the raw data is pushed from my service provider. I know I did exactly the same with just a Date Column and it worked great. Is there away I am not telling it to look up the current Column format?

Or am I missing something totally different here?

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, FROM e_track_access_log 
        WHERE datetime_accessed = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 DAY AND member_id >'0' 
        ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,5");
?>
<br>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

This is the whole code I am using then the Echo's but they too long to post here

Comment: You have an open parenthesis without a matching close parenthesis. And where is the code that actually performs the query?

Comment: Why are you subtracting `INTERVAL 0 DAY`? That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following condition to get all records for the current day:

```
WHERE DATE(datetime_accessed) = CURDATE()
```

The condition you have only matches rows where the time is `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

> SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime_accessed , '%y,%m,%d') FROM e_track_access_log WHERE DATE(datetime_accessed) = CURDATE() AND member_id >'0' ORDER BY datetime_accessed DESC LIMIT 0,5